# Cobordant 1-manifolds are homologous?

Tags: homology-cohomology, cobordism

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and suppose that $\Sigma \subset M \times[0,1]$ is a surface such that $\partial \Sigma \subset \partial (M \times [0,1])= M \times \{0,1\}$. Denote by $\pi$ the projection onto the first factor for $M \times[0,1]$. Since $\Sigma$ admits a triangulation whose boundary is a triangulation of $\partial \Sigma$, it follows that $[\pi(\partial \Sigma)] \in H_1(M;\mathbb{Z})$ is zero.

This seems like a perfectly reasonable argument to me. Nevertheless, when I started to work through some examples, I found that this is readily demonstrated to be false even in the simplest case of $M$ being the torus considered as a quotient of $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ in the standard way. Start off with the loop $\{1/2\} \times [0,1]$ and pull the component $\{1/2\} \times (2/5,3/5)$ around longitudinally until it (almost) touches itself at the point $(1/2,4/5)$, then perform surgery which corresponds to a saddle cobordism (by cutting out two arcs and gluing them back to the 4 resulting boundary points, but the other way around). The resultant curve is a meridian plus two longitudes at the level of homology. Where am I going wrong in my reasoning?? Any and all insights are welcome.

Comment: Since you use homology with $\mathbb{Z}/2$ coefficients, the two longitudes cancel each other. So you are left with an initial meridian and a final meridian (which have opposite orientation (not that it really matters here due to the coefficients)), so the boundary is here indeed the zero homology class. In fact, as I understand your example, the two longitudes also have opposite orientations, so the class is zero with any general coefficients.

Comment: Jordan -- you're of course correct in the case of $\mathbb{Z}/2$ coefficients! Thanks for pointing that out. However, in the case of $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients, I do believe that the longitudes have the same orientation. If so, I don't see why my argument works for $\mathbb{Z}/2$ coefficients but not for $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients =)

Comment: I'm not quite sure about what is your example, but orientation is everything in this matter. If we think of $M$ as $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ (with boundary segments appropriately identified), then I guess the initial meridian is say $\{1/2\} \times [0,1]$ oriented upwards. You move the part $\{1/2\} \times (1/3, 2/3)$ to the left for one full turn, then perform some surgery. You're left (modulo an overall switch in orientation) with the same meridian plus $[0,1] \times \{1/3\}$ oriented leftward and $[0,1] \times \{2/3\}$ oriented rightward.

Comment: Jordan -- Ah, it would seem to me that we don't have the same surgery in mind here and that this is the crux of the issue! In my construction, you take the part $\{1/2\} \times (1/3,2/3)$ and pull it to the left one full turn, but also lift it up a little bit so that it glue to the portion of the curve $\{1/2\} \times (2/3,1)$ using the surgery corresponding to a saddle cobordism. In this case would you agree that the result is a 1-cycle which is homologous to 1 meridian and 2 longitudes?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that I see what you mean. When one performs a 'surgery' (or more generally 'disconnect' two intersecting curves & 'reconnect' the four local pieces), one has to glue back in a way compatible with the local orientations of the four local pieces; this is a constraint. The way I understand your example, this procedure can't produce a 'saddle surgery' (except when working with $\mathbb{Z}/2$ coefficients in which case there no local orientations acting as constraints); each interpretation of your example I considered has two opposite longitudes (which cancel in $H_1$).

Comment: Jordan — thanks so much! I think I’ve finally figured it out. I had been assumed I was working in the oriented bordism category but it turns out that my bordism was nonorientable (this is equivalent to your observation that the corresponding surgery did not respect orientation.) thanks so much again!